# Google Plus Button counter acts differently with URL's that includes https

Tags: google-plus-one

As you can discover from http://www.google.com/webmasters/+1/button/

Google+ has different counters for;

http://plus.google.com/-pageid- or https://plus.google.com/-pageid-

In my case URL without https displays 18 +1's while url with https displays 2 +1's.

The problem is 18 +1's did not displayed on Google Plus page so i can't interact with these users.

Meanwhile, other Google tools such as badges counts url with https.

Is there any way to merge these users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google+ still has different counters in SSL and Non-SSL mode.

SSL and Non-SSL version of the Google Plus seems working independently so i could not found any way to count +1 of the same URL in the SSL and non-SSL area.